# Did Morel find back his pipe?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I remember Morel and Shaiapouf have a fight and Shaiapouf won the fight and took Morel pipe and threw it somewhere else. *I remember he threw it into the sea if no mistake.

So after the fight did Morel find back his pipe? If he didn't have his pipe that mean he is useless currently right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Did Morel find back his pipe?** As stated in the [wiki](https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Morel_Mackernasey#Equipment),

> It is unknown if Morel retrieved or replaced it afterwards.

Given where the manga is now, I doubt we'll see if he retrieved it soon *since the focus is currently in the expedition to the Dark Continent and the succession war between the princes of the Kakin empire* and as far as I know, he isn't in the expedition nor as one of the guards of the princes, unlike the other hunters.

**If he didn't have his pipe, that mean he is useless, currently, right?** I wouldn't assume that easily since [he has other sets of abilities aside from those that requires the use of his giant pipe](https://hunterxhunter.fandom.com/wiki/Morel_Mackernasey#Abilities_.26_Powers). Also, the pipe isn't anything special or that can only be made via certain means so he can easily find a replacement, or find the one who originally made his first pipe, although as to who made his pipe originally is currently also unknown.

Comment: wait so currently the manga is on going right now?

Comment: @kit The manga is currently at Chapter 390, which is the succession arc that I described. I believed it stopped last year, although I hope it continues soon.